# C++ accessing variables from .CPP files

Tags: c++, static, namespaces, extern

I'm a little fuzzy on how variable access between .cpp files works. For instance:

#### main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    int a = i;
    return 0;
}
```

#### main2.cpp

```
int i;
```

This generates a compiler error on main.cpp, telling me there is no in i in existence. What difference then, does the "static" keyword do in this context? (I tried Googling for it, but most of the "static keyword" info pages talk about classes & functions)

#### main2.cpp

```
static int i;
```

Is it the same? Does it prevent `extern int i` being used to access `i` elsewhere? How does the use of anonymous namespaces differ in how variables are handled?

#### main2.cpp

```
namespace
{
    int i;
}
```

---

To sum up:

- Can variables be accessed between .cpp files? (aside from extern keyword)
- How does the static keyword on a global variable affect things?
- How do anonymous namespaces affect things differently?

Comment: I don't think it's fair to change the question that much if nobody has requested clarification.

Comment: To answer the new question: It doesn't. It saves you the trouble of writing `namespace { }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, `main2.cpp` defines a global variable `i`, which *could have* been accessed by `main.cpp` if an `extern` declaration of `i` had appeared in that file.  (Normally that extern declaration would come from a header file.)  You got a compiler error because `i` had never been declared in `main.cpp`, which means the compiler assumes there is no such variable.

In your second example, `main2.cpp` defines a *file scope* variable `i`.  File scope variables are distinct from globals, even if they happen to have the same name.  If you had had an extern declaration of `i` in `main.cpp` in the second example, both files would have *compiled* successfully, but then you would have gotten a link error because no *global* variable `i` was defined.

If you renamed `main2.cpp` from the second example to `main3.cpp`, added an extern declaration of `i` to `main.cpp`, compiled all three and linked them all together, that would succeed; main.cpp and main2.cpp would share one variable named `i`, and `main3.cpp` would have its own *entirely separate* variable also named `i`.

This stuff is called *linkage*.  Namespaces are almost entirely unrelated to linkage.  However, the anonymous namespace is special.  Defining a variable in an anonymous namespace is *for all practical purposes* the same as defining it with `static` -- it makes it a file scope variable.  (If I remember correctly, there is a difference, but it only matters if you are doing complicated things with exported templates, and as exported templates are so little used that they're talking about deleting the feature from the C++ standard, you don't have to worry about it.)

The value of the anonymous namespace is that you can put a *class definition* inside it, and that makes all of the class's methods be file-local.  (Only the `class { ... }` block has to be inside the `namespace { ... }` block to get this effect.)  You can't do that any other way.

Answer (score 2):

All global variables have some kind of *linkage*. `extern` linkage is required to name the same variable in different contexts between different files.

`extern` is the default. If you actually use `extern` in a variable declaration, it's treated as  a reference to another file. Omit any linkage specifier to actually create the variable; this must happen in only one file.

```
extern int i; // i exists somewhere in some .cpp file.
int i; // ah! this is the file it exists in. 
       // (Although nothing special about that.)
```

`static` applied to a global (at namespace scope) makes it local to the file. You get the same effect from a private namespace, so `static` outside function or class scope is deprecated. Many still use it though.

The exception to the rule of `static` meaning file-local is in classes and `inline` functions. Class `static` members should more properly be called `extern` since the semantics are identical. It's ugly and confusing, but I guess Bjarne just wanted to eliminate `extern` as a keyword.

Inline functions can have the same definition among multiple `.cpp` files, so when one creates a `static` variable, the variable definition is shared as well.

Comment: I guess it's technically true that in C++ you have to "actually create" a variable only once, but every compiler I've ever used has been perfectly fine with merging extern-less "int i;" in two or more files.  (Left over from C, I suppose, where those are "tentative definitions" and merging is obligatory.)

Comment: @Zack: Every compiler I've used was totally anal about it. The main practical issue is that they may be initialized to different values.

Comment: IME they only get anal if more than one extern-less declaration has an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

- yes, for example you can use static class variables
- it makes variable local and persistent to compilation unit
- anonymous namespace prevents collision between symbols.  it is as if you create uniquely named namespace manually